# Run scheduler to execute jobs at an interval from the completion of the previous job

Tags: scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, job-scheduling, crontrigger

I need to create schedulers to execute jobs(class files) at specified intervals..For Now, I'm using Quartz Scheduler which triggers the jobs at defined intervals from the time of triggering of it.

**For Eg:** Consider I'm giving a cron expression to run for every one hour starting at morning 9.My first run will be at 9 and my second run will be at 10 and so on.
If my job is taking 20 minutes to execute then in that case this method is not that much efficient.

What I need to do is to schedule a job for every one hour from the completion time of the previously ran job

**For Eg:** Consider my job to run every one hour is triggered at 9 and for the first run it took 20 minutes to run, so for the next time the job should trigger only at 10:20 instead of 10 (ie., one hour from the completion of previous ran job)

I need to know whether there are any methods in Quartz Scheduling to achieve this or any other logic I need to do.

If anyone could help me out on this,it would be very helpful for me.

Comment: If anyone knows please help me in this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by job-chaining your job executions. There are various approaches you can choose from:

(1) Implement a Quartz [JobListener](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/JobListener.html) and in its `jobWasExecuted` method, that is invoked by Quartz whenever a job finishes executing, re-fire your job.

(2) Look at the Quartz [JobChainingJobListener](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/listeners/JobChainingJobListener.html) that you can use to implement simple job chaining scenarios. Please note that the functionality of this listener is very limited as it does not allow you to insert delays between job executions, there is no support for conditions that must be met before target jobs are executed etc. But you can use it as a good starting point to implement (1).

(3) Use [QuartzDesk](https://www.quartzdesk.com) (our commercial product) or any other product that allows you to create job chains while externalizing and managing all job dependencies **outside** of your application. A job chain can have multiple target jobs that can be executed immediately, with a fixed delay or at arbitrary time in the future produced by a JavaScript expression. It also allows you to implement somewhat more sophisticated works flows, such as firing a target job when multiple source jobs complete their execution etc. I am attaching screenshots showing you what a simple job chain that re-executes Job1 with a 1 minute delay upon Job1's completion (with any job execution status) looks like:

[image: Job Chain Condition]
[image: Job Chain Target Jobs]

Comment: Thanks Jan Moravec you saved my day..:)